# Save vertices to texture and pass to shader

Tags: javascript, three.js, textures, shader

Finally got some time to play with shaders, but got stuck in one moment. I want to pass the vertices to a shader and make some gpgpu on it.

Gpgpu is working fine I guess because i see few pixels and one in the center being pushed to the side as i put in code just for testing.

Now i want to pass the sphere vertices. Here are the steps I am taking. Please point out errors :-)

edit: fiddle added - [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/ec5zU/)

1) Creating geometry, and passing it to data array.

```
geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 0.2, 15, 15 );
console.log(geometry.vertices.length);
var a = new Float32Array(geometry.vertices.length * 4);
for(var k=0; k<geometry.vertices.length; k++) {
                a[ k*4 + 0 ] = geometry.vertices[k].x;
                a[ k*4 + 1 ] = geometry.vertices[k].y;
                a[ k*4 + 2 ] = geometry.vertices[k].z;
                a[ k*4 + 3 ] = 1;   
}
```

2) Save it in data texture

```
posTexture[2] = new THREE.DataTexture(a, 16, 16, THREE.RGBAFormat, THREE.FloatType);
```

3) Set the 'Set scene' (it should pass the datatexture to it once)
    setUniforms = {
        posTexture: {type: "t", value: posTexture[2]}
    };

```
var setMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: setUniforms,
    vertexShader:   document.getElementById('setVert').textContent,
    fragmentShader: document.getElementById('setFrag').textContent,
    wireframe: true
});

var setPlane = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(16,16), setMaterial);
setScene.add(setPlane);
```

4) Set the shaders.

```
<script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="setVert">

    // switch on high precision floats
    #ifdef GL_ES
    precision highp float;
    #endif
    varying vec2 vUv;
    uniform sampler2D posTexture;

    void main(){
        vUv = uv;
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position,1.0);
    }

</script>
<script type="x-shader/x-fragment" id="setFrag">

    #ifdef GL_ES
    precision highp float;
    #endif
    uniform sampler2D posTexture;
    varying vec2 vUv;

    void main(){
        vec3 color = texture2D( posTexture, vUv ).xyz;

        gl_FragColor = vec4(col, 1.0);
    }
</script>
```

5) Animate it!!! start sets the SetShader to save the data and output a WebGLRenderTarget to next shaders: one responsible for doing calculations and giving back a texture with coordinates, next one for displaying

```
function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    renderer.setViewport(0,0,16, 16);
    if(buffer == 0) {
        buffer = 1;
        a = 0;
        b = 1;
    } else {
        buffer = 0;
        a = 1;
        b = 0;
    }

    if(start) {
        renderer.render(setScene, processCamera, posTexture[a]);
        start = false;
    }

    posUniforms.posTexture.value = posTexture[a];
    renderer.render(posScene, processCamera, posTexture[b])
    dispUniforms.posTexture.value = posTexture[b];
    renderer.setViewport(0,0,dispSize.x, dispSize.y);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
```

Comment: For one thing, your fragment shader should not even compile (`col` is undefined). Another, an RGBA texture is ***Unsigned*** Normalized; you generally do not want to spit vertex positions directly into this kind of a texture because you will lose any coordinate that is < 0. Assuming it stores clip-space vertex positions, where w = 1.0, then you want to multiply by **0.5** and add **0.5** before writing the position to `gl_FragColor` for output to the texture.

Comment: so how the positions are saved in this one? http://www.chromeexperiments.com/detail/one-million-particles/?f=

Answer (score 93):

I had to polish the shader code slightly, it seemed a bit messy to me ^^ http://jsfiddle.net/ec5zU/1/

Well, you're trying to push sphere vertices down to the gpu. The very fact that you want to do that indicates that you might not have quite understood the concept of gpgpu. It is there to calculate stuff (algorithms, maths) on the GPU. It’s a concept to work with the GPU without doing / displaying 3D-related stuff.

Passing sphere vertices into a texture and then doing something with that texture makes no sense to me – but maybe I just didn’t quite understand what you’re trying to do. So could you maybe elaborate more on your final goal with that gpgpu approach?

In the demo textures are used for the following reason: You can easily move data from the CPU (the JavaScript) to the GPU (like with uniforms, attributes) but it's harder the other way round. One possibility is to have a seperate render target for your GPU which result you'll save as a texture after the render cycle is complete. Then you sort of "stored your data".

Including the comments to this answer what I'm trying to say is: I recommend learning some more about shaders and three.js because most of the time stuff can be done easier and better. And if that demo case is important then try to implement the fixes me and  Andon M. Coleman gave you, and think about your sphere logic and how you want to implement it 'cause the way you're doing it now doesn't make too much sense...

If you're sure that there's no better way than creating and reassigning the positions over textures every frame, then so be it :) I played around for another hour, added comments, changed some stuff, fixed the worst parts, and now you see a red dot moving across the screen: http://jsfiddle.net/ec5zU/2/ I won't invest any more time though 'cause I think stackoverflow's not meant to have your project coded ^^ I hope I could provide some help nonetheless and that you have a starting point again, since something is now actually "working and moving".

(Stackoverflow tells me to include some code. So there's some polished shader code at the bottom.)

```
   <script type="x-shader/x-fragment" id="fragmentshader">
    
        precision highp float;
        
        varying vec2 vUv;
        uniform sampler2D posTexture;

        void main()
        {
            vec3 color = texture2D(posTexture, vUv).rgb;
            color.x += 0.01;
            gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);

        }
    
    </script>
```

Comment: i want to distort and animate the sphere with some functions, so I assume gpgpu will be perfect for this ? How can you otherwise get previous positions?

I was trying to do it like in here http://www.chromeexperiments.com/detail/one-million-particles/?f= but obviously i failed...

Comment: So what you want to do is to just display a bunch of pixels on screen..? You don't need gpgpu for that, forget about it. There are a few ways to solve this, the most obvious and flexible (and easiest as it's precoded by THREE.js) being THREE.ParticleSystem. You'd then create a custom vertex- and fragmentshader (just 1 of each) where you have some logics in it.
If you don't know what a fragment/vertex shader is or how to create one I recommend reading up some tutorials like http://aerotwist.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-shaders-part-1/.

Comment: So what you'd do in a THREE.js sense is you'd create a BufferGeometry with a "position" attribute (there are tons of examples for this) and maybe fill it with 100k positions. Try first with the "ParticleSystemMaterial", and when it runs well you create a custom shader like in the tutorial above and use that one instead of THREE.ParticleSystemMaterial. In those shaders you can have your logic then: In the vertex shader you define where the position is now, and in the fragment shader how it looks like.

Comment: In the example you posted the creator also probably defined a uniform with the mouse-coordinates. This uniform is then used in the vertex shader where he calculates the attraction between the vertex's current position towards the mouse coordinates. And then he adds/substracts some x/y speed for the current vertex depending on distance and time passed :)
Enjoy creating your own!

Comment: In the post you linked they sort of "save variables in textures" between renderings. In your case you just want to distort / animate a sphere, so you don't even need that (You don't need DataTexture or anything like that if you don't want to output data from the shader - which is sort of the concept of gpgpu). I would first try without anyways. So your positions for the BufferGeometry would probably be random points on a sphere. As uniforms you could e.g. have the mouse coordinates. In the vertex shader you'd then have your logic to set the new position.

Comment: I want to use it in my vector field (http://marky.pl/vu/vf/) . Performing calculation on the gpu will allow me to get more particles, but to do this i need to get the position of each particle from previous iteration - thats why i need to output it to a texture and get it back :)

Comment: wow, looking nice! Ok but if it's just that why not do it on the GPU directly? And there's also a lot of other room for improvements. First, use a BufferGeometry with the dynamic flag. Secondly, and yes that's asked a lot, redesign the way it works! You can calculate everything per vertex if you e.g. pass the time as uniform and the noise as attribute. This is for example how primitive water is done: You multiply time with a sinus curve and bring in the vertex position to simulate waves. Do the same, make it able to calculate its own absolute position in the vertex shader! blazing performance!

Comment: I want to calculate the noise inside the shader, not pass it as an attribute. I need to have the previous position, because it adds noise value from given xyz coordinates to move the particles. Thats why i want to put the data into texture, to be able to read in next iteration particle coordinates and add new displacement.

Comment: If you're sure that there's no better way than creating and reassigning the positions over textures every frame, then so be it :) I played around for another hour, added comments, changed some stuff, and now you see a red dot moving across the screen: http://jsfiddle.net/ec5zU/2/ I won't invest any more time though 'cause I think stackoverflow's not meant to have your project coded ^^ I hope I could provide some help nonetheless and that you have a starting point again, since something is now actually "working and moving". Good luck and have fun!

Comment: Thank You, also the dot was working earlier :)  still it is not the answer to the question

Comment: Was it? The dot didn't move for me in the first place (now it's moving). And not moving = your shaders didn't interact. That's what I fixed, and I believe you're on the right way now. Yet, as mentioned, I can't code the stuff myself. If you feel it's too hard to code it yourself then maybe you should leave it be for the time being... If you feel like there's something very specific you don't understand yet or a line of code you can't get to work then I'll still gladly to help.